# Incremental sync of 2 repositories on different networks

Tags: git, version-control

In my setup, I have a Git repository that I work on. On another network (with no access to my main network), I have another Git repository that is read only that I want to keep synced up with the main repository. I'd like to do this occasionally to make sure that the closed repository is up to date with the main. I would also like to avoid having to send a full clone of the repository every time I want to update the closed repository.

Previously, I would use Subversion's svnadmin dump and restore commands to do this incremental updating of the closed repository, but unsure how to do it with Git?

Are there Git commands, or ideally a Git UI, that allow me to do this?

Is Git patching the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect in your case I would simply occasionally connect my laptop to the 'other' network and push branches from my local clone. However, you might want to look into [git bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) which basically allows push/pull via sneaker-net. You can create a bundle file containing a set of commits (eg: `git bundle create update.bundle last-update-tag HEAD`) then take this bundle to your non-networked device and you can pull it (`git pull update.bundle`). Quite useful for USB stick transfers.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like git bundle is the way to go. Tested this out last night and works beautifully, especially if you use tags to mark your last increment.